# mongodb : fetch API POST request returns a strange response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express, fetch-api

I want to send POST request to mongodb using fetch API. GET request was implemented successfully using fetch API but POST request wasn't.

In the console log, POST request returns weird response as bellow:

```
{n: 1, opTime: {…}, electionId: "7fffffff0000000000000001", ok: 1}
electionId:"7fffffff0000000000000001"
n:1
ok:1
opTime:{ts: "6490526445679411201", t: 1}
__proto__:Object
```

I have never run into this response and I don't know what it means...

My code is as below.

server.js

```
app.post('/recipe', (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body); // this console.log returns empty object : {}

db.collection('recipe').insertOne(req.body, (err, result) => {
   if (err) return console.log(err);
   console.log('saved to database')
   res.json(result);
   });
});
```

index.js

```
class App extends Component {
   constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state={
        results: [],
        name: '',
        ingredients: '',
        descriptions: '',
        modal: false
     }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

 handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, ingredients, descriptions } = this.state;
    fetch('/recipe', {
       method: 'POST',
       body: JSON.stringify({
       name,
       ingredients,
       descriptions
       }),
    headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    })
   .then( res => res.json())
   .then( res => console.log(res)); //this console.log returns strange response
   }   

 render() {

 const { name, ingredients, descriptions } = this.state;
 return (
   <div className="App"> 
    <h1>Recipe List</h1> 
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <input
        value={name}
        type="text"
        onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}
        placeholder="name" />
      <input
        value={ingredients}
        type="text"
        onChange={e => this.setState({ ingredients: e.target.value })}                
        placeholder="ingredients" />
      <input
        value={descriptions}
        type="text"
        onChange={e => this.setState({ descriptions: e.target.value })}
        placeholder="descriptions" />

         <input type="submit" onClick={this.toggle}/>
       </form>
    </div>           
    )
   }
  }

  export default App;
```

Thank you for your help in advance,

Comment: Have you tried adding the `headers` as part of the object you pass right after the url you're requesting to?

Comment: sorry, what is p.o? @fshock

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited the question

Comment: Never mind, you did

Comment: no problem. Many problem related fetch API was 'header' so I added after reading other answers in stackoverflow, though it didn't work..

Answer (score 2):

mongoDB **insertOne** returns information of success or not.
if you want to get inserted data, try this.

```
db.collection('recipe').insertOne(req.body,(err, result)=>{
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log('saved to database');
    res.json(result.ops[0]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Now console.log returns object with _id. `{_id: "5a1309995f82754b4c4baaa4"}
_id
:
"5a1309995f82754b4c4baaa4"
__proto__
:
Object`  What I'm wondering is that why it didn't contain body data? @godsenal

Comment: mongodb api doesn't give you inserted doc. You've already got data in req.body! You just need to add _id if you need. Or you can use mongoose instead.

Comment: I checked in both Postman and mLab, it was empty and it only has id: `{
        "_id": "5a130d53fdbaa54b8a22af85"
    }`  Also `req.body` in the terminal is empty. `listening on 8080
{}
saved to database`

Comment: So.. it was not mongodb problem. r u using body parser?